# Does WordPress auto-generate tags?

Tags: wordpress, tags, divi-theme

I'm currently managing some of the backend stuff for a Divi WordPress site for a local marketing company. I'm far from an expert, and the site is kind of a disaster. One of the things I've been trying to do for searchablity's sake is clean up all the post tags so that, for example, there are not 3 different business names for one business listing. I did this obviously under Posts --> Tags. But after doing this, different names are re-appearing again for individual listings. Even though I've been careful to use the same ones that I'd already created.

Its a small company and I asked if anyone is adding tags elsewhere on the site that might causing this, and every one said no. So I'm wondering if WordPress auto-generates these tags somehow? It's really annoying in terms of throwing a wrench into the site's searchability, and since I've already spent hours cleaning them up for dozens of posts and listings.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress by default will not auto create tags.

Are these posts manually created? If not, how are they added?

If they are using a plugin to auto generate the posts from something like an RSS feed this could be adding tags.

I've ran into something similar with a site dealing with stocks pulling in multiple posts from multiple sources and the owner didn't like that.

Comment: Yes, each post is manually created. Which is part of the reason why I'm confused where the tags coming from, if someone isn't adding them manually. I think they do use a plug-in to pull social media posts onto the site. Whether or not that's creating tags might be something to look into.

Comment: What plugin is it?

Comment: Two of them called Instagram Feed Pro and Facebook Feed.